# OpenCV FaceRecognizer - facial recognition. Does anyone know of a link

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, face-detection, face-recognition

With the class FaceRecognizer of OpenCV anybody has a link to somewhere explaining with available source code how to use it to save a model from images (say cropped tags of the same person in photos) and then with any other image that wasn't used to make the model load the model saved of the person(s) (possibly previously stored in db) and find a match on a photo from the stored model therefore calling it facial recognition? This would be a breakthrough for a small social network I have that already uses facial detection to tag people now I need the facial recognition to be able to implement automatically tagging in photos recognizing the users in the images.

Been looking but can't find source code, it's been over a year since the class has been released, for facial detection there's source code as to detect nose, ears, eyes, eyebrows, mouth, etc but not for facial recognition.

Have tried from the official opencv site with the documentation they have, they do post source code in chunks making you think how to put the code in order but haven't been able to compile what I had created to save the model "trained" from an array of photos.

Comment: you seem to confuse *detection* (face or not?) and *recognition* (who is it?) here

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you are more than mistaken. There are lots and lots of face 
recognition documentation.

Just a quick search on google, http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html

Is this the documentation you are talking about? There are many examples, pretty clear cut and straight forward with source code. Which part are you having problems from the documentation? The codes are not in chunks, and it's the whole code by itself. Do comment on my answer so I can help you.

If this is not the documentation you talking about, then have a look at it. Example source code all included inside. Cheers.

Last but not least, when you say trained, you are talking about classifier? If you already have trained it, there's no need to compile it, just insert the path of the classifier into the program.

Comment: @ibennet, was it what you are looking for? If not, do comment, so I can help you more. Cheers(: